# Spring Boot - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext and Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext

Tags: grails, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application ([Grails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grails_%28framework%29) 3.1.8), but when I run the application in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:292)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:510)
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
```

I tried adding javax-servlet-api dependency as suggested in [an answer to *Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24393684/constructor-threw-exception-nested-exception-is-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror/24394329#24394329)

But then I started getting:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at closemytab.Application.main(Application.groovy:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

This post then suggests to remove the javax-servlet-api: [Spring boot -- Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021328/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-embe)

But then I face the original issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The issue was with the *build.gradle* file:

```
provided "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) wasn't happy with the provided.

As soon as I switched to

```
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
```

the application worked.

Comment: In maven, I changed the scope like this: `<scope>provided</scope>` to `<scope>compile</scope>` and it worked!!. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm <3

Comment: Note that the 'provided' scope is there for a reason. You don't want your deployables to contain the servlet APIs or other web application server artifacts - this can potentially lead to all kinds of runtime errors when your application gets deployed. In my opinion it is better to use a Spring Boot Run configuration to fix aforementioned error.

Comment: @Walco I partially understand you point, could you please post your solution? Maybe could be the right answer for other people. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Run with a [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) goal:

`spring-boot:run`

Steps to set up Maven configuration in [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA):

Menu *Debug/Run Configuration* → Click on the + button visible at the top left → Select *Maven* → Set command line to `spring-boot:run`.

Comment: Using this suggestion instead of running the class directly from the project explorer in IntelliJ got rid of my ClassNotFoundException I was seeing when trying to debug in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 17):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you need to enable ' Include dependencies with "Provider" scope in menu *Run* → *Edit Configurations* → *Application* → 'your main class' (by default it's disabled)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Adding the dependency below fixed my issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Remember to have a parent dependency as well!

Comment: Thanks this fixes it for me (spring n00b here). How come it does not auto add it however? - project builds fine without it but will crash with dreaded java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

Answer (score 1):

For me, it's because of the Tomcat version. I changed Tomcat version from 7.5 to 8.5, and the problem's solved.

Answer (score 1):

`Exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext` only means you are not providing the Tomcat dependency to your application. In case you are using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), it’s really simple to do that as shown below.

Select your project → open the Maven panel (it mostly resides on the top right side of the panel) → select embedded.

[image: Click here for a screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for the **maven** project and what I did was

1. Select Modify Options

[image]

2. Select the option **Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath**

[image]

3. Apply the changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem replace

```
implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl' --> implementation group: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl', name: 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api', version: '3.0.0'
```