# Why do we need to reconfigure with SpringBootServletInitializer to build war for external Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, build, war

**1-**  I am adding below configurations in Spring Boot application to build war file to deploy on external tomcat server and I am able to build successfully.

**2 -** But my problem is I am unable to run Spring boot application in my IDE(IntelliJ IDEA) and getting below error with build configuration.

**3 -** I am expecting that I can run application with tomcat configuration for build as well as for development in IDE with same configuration so that again and again I don't have to remove configuration to run in IDE.

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.15</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lucifer</groupId>
    <artifactId>Thymeleaf_Demo</artifactId>
    <version>v1</version>
    <name>Thymeleaf_Demo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <description>Thymeleaf project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                 <!--Added for build war-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>EMS</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Main Method**

```
package com.lucifer.lab;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ThymeleafDemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ThymeleafDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Console Error**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::               (v2.7.15)

2023-09-06 22:58:47.092  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.lucifer.lab.ThymeleafDemoApplication   : Starting ThymeleafDemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_202 on LPT2973 with PID 11796 (D:\Workspace\DCB\Thymeleaf_Demo\target\classes started by sampleUser in D:\Workspace\DCB\Thymeleaf_Demo)
2023-09-06 22:58:47.094  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.lucifer.lab.ThymeleafDemoApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-09-06 22:58:47.207  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-09-06 22:58:47.467  WARN 11796 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lucifer.lab.ThymeleafDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2023-09-06 22:58:47.537 ERROR 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.lucifer.lab.ThymeleafDemoApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:188) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) [spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) [spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) [spring-boot-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
    at com.lucifer.lab.ThymeleafDemoApplication.main(ThymeleafDemoApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) [spring-boot-devtools-2.7.15.jar:2.7.15]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:162) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:402) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:325) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:206) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:459) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467) ~[spring-core-5.3.29.jar:5.3.29]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
    ... 28 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

*Please anyone guide how I can run spring without removing build (war) configuration. or give me some other way to configure where I can run application in IDE and able to build when required without removing configurations.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext in JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19690267/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-servletcontext-in-junit)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Jens.  but still problem not solved.